# How do I remove ALL TRACES of Adobe CS6?

Tags: software, lightroom, photoshop

I have been testing Adobe CS6 over the last month and the trial ran out yesterday.
I have decided that it's over the top for my needs at the moment, so have downloaded the Lightroom trial.

However, after uninstalling CS6 and installing Lightroom, it still thinks the (Lightroom) trial has expired, so I can only assume that there is some sort of license management software left in the machine, or a registry entry?

Is there an in-depth un-installer available? (Like Symantec have for their software.) Or can anyone point me towards the hidden file or registry area to edit/remove?

I'm in Windows 7.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you can download and use the **Adobe Creative Suite Cleaner Tool** to clear the errors in the uninstall..

Download from the following link and try that:
http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html 

Download and "Run as Administrator" and then restart your machine.

Comment: Does this tool help? Or still the problem persists?

Comment: Thanks for that - ive not had a chance to run it yet, will do this evening :-)

Comment: the above method seems to work for me.. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue with mac osx mavericks.. Is this cleaner   tool available for mac osx?

Comment: Does this give you infinite trial or not?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Just tried it and it doesn't remove whatever files keep the trial info...